# Creating asp.net server control template

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, templates, servercontrols

I'm trying to create to templates for my server control(caption template and content template).

```
<uc:MyControl ID="myConrol1" runat="server">
    <CaptionTemplate>
        <%# Eval("MyCaption") %>
    </CaptionTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <b><%# Eval("MyContent") %></b>
    </ContentTemplate>
</uc:MyControl>
```

And then give templates with datasource

```
var ds = new List<CarouselItem>
                {
                    new CarouselItem()
                        {
                            MyCaption = "Slide 1 caption",
                            MyContent = "Slide 1 content"
                        },
                    new CarouselItem()
                        {
                            MyCaption = "Slide 2 caption",
                            MyContent = "Slide 2 content"
                        }
                };

myConrol1.DataSource = ds;
myConrol1.DataBind();
```

However what I've tried doesn't work for me. Here is the code I've tried to achieve this functionality.

```
[Browsable(false), DefaultValue(null), Description("The content template."), TemplateContainer(typeof(MyItemContainer)), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public virtual ITemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }

[Browsable(false), DefaultValue(null), Description("The caption template."), TemplateContainer(typeof(MyItemContainer)), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public virtual ITemplate CaptionTemplate { get; set; }
```

Then I've created

```
public class MyItemContainer : WebControl, INamingContainer
        {
            private readonly MyItem item;
            public MyItemContainer (MyItem ai)
            {
                item = ai;
            }

            public MyItem DataItem
            {
                get { return item; }
            }
        }
```

And then in bind method wrote InstantiateIn to this class

```
foreach (object dataSourceObject in ds)
            {
                var item = new MyItem
                    {
                        Caption = new PlaceHolder(),
                        Content = new PlaceHolder(),
                        DataItem = dataSourceObject 
                    };

                if (ContentTemplate != null)
                {
                    MyAccordionItemContainer cc = new MyAccordionItemContainer(item);
                    ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(cc);
                    item.Content.Controls.Add(cc);
                }

                if (CaptionTemplate != null)
                {
                    MyAccordionItemContainer cc = new MyAccordionItemContainer(item);
                    CaptionTemplate.InstantiateIn(cc);

                    item.Caption.Controls.Add(cc);
                }

                item.DataBind();
            }
```

No everything in page is empty and not binded. Seems I'm not using `dataSourceObject` in instantiating process, but I'm not sure how to use him. Have anyone any idea here?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inheriting from the WebControl class, you may want to have a look at the DataBoundControl instead and overriding the "PerformDataBinding" method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol(v=vs.100).aspx